# TinyMCE issues: converting newline to <br />

Tags: tinymce

I just upgraded to the latest version of tinymce and discovered that when I update content, the content is messed up with `<br>` tags. I've tried a couple of configuration settings including:

- convert_newlines_to_brs:false
- force_p_newlines: true
- force_br_newlines : false

all to no avail.

Has anyone else experienced and solved this problem?

Comment: do those brs get submitted when you save the editor content? brs are necessary for the FF in order to be able to click inside an empty paragraph/div

Comment: Yes, I can see the brs in my database. I tried the last version of tinymce I used and everything works ok but the newest version seems to be the one with the bug or perhaps I'm missing out a configuration setting.

Comment: what version did you use and what version are you using now?

Comment: The version with the bug is 3.4.2. The version I reverted to is 2.1.2.

Comment: hmm, in this case i fear i can't help you. i am using 3.3.9 and  i will switch to 3.4.x if this is a stable version (actually it is not). I suggest you switch to 3.3.x .

Comment: Alright thanks. I think I'll do just that while keeping my fingers crossed for the latest stable version.

Comment: +1 for given question information on request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, in this case i fear i can't help you directly. I am using 3.3.9 and i will switch to 3.4.x if this is a stable version (actually it is not). I suggest you switch to 3.3.x .